# Issues with onCreate() for different versions of Android

Tags: android, android-activity

My Android App seems to be working perfectly well for Jelly Bean (4.1–4.3.1) and above, but, it faces issues for Ice Cream Sandwich (4.0–4.0.4) and below. As far as I know, the onCreate() should be called only once when an activity is created and it is called only once for Jelly Bean (4.1–4.3.1) and above, but, unfortunately, for Ice Cream Sandwich (4.0–4.0.4) and below, when I open the App again after the interval of 3-4 hours, the onCreate() is called as many time as I open my App.

Any guidance or help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: What are the chances that you're opening the same activity more than once inside your application code? onCreate state should be open only once, when your activity is been created.

Comment: post your activity code

Comment: The chances that I am opening the same activity is nil. My activity is being killed by Android during those 3-4 hours. I need to make sure that when the Activity is being recreated again, the onCreate should not be called again, but, the last activity should be restored. Note that there is no issue for newer versions.

Comment: When Android restarts your app after it has been killed. It must reinstantiate the `Activity` and it must call `onCreate()` again on it. This is standard Android and works the same on all versions. Please be more specific about your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the [activity lifecycle](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html):

[image]

What is happening is probably that your activity is getting killed by Android during these 3-4 hours, and when it is recreated onCreate() is called.

Comment: Does that mean that onCreate() can be called more than once? What should I do to make sure that it even if it is being recreated, the last activity should be restored and onCreate should not be called again?

Comment: You can't prevent onCreate from being called. If you have something that you want to be run once and only once, like retrieving remote data, consider storing the instance state in onStop() and retrieving it from the local storage in onCreate() instead of accessing the remote server. Take a look at http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/recreating.html

Comment: Godsmith is right, you can use android sharedpreferences in order to save all your data on onStop state and read it again onCreate state. If the data already  exists don't perform your methods on onCreate state.

Comment: You can easily recreate this scenario - open your app and then some memory consuming one - e.g. AngryBirds or facebook/instagram and scroll a lot. Android OS will destroy your activity and it will be recreated, when you open it again.